# configuring axis in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

x = np.random.rand(200) and y = 12 * x - 4 + np.random.randn(200)
After ploting the (x,y) values I get the following graph in matplotlib:
[image]

How can I configure the axis so all samples are clearly visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the `scatter` function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(200)
y = 12 * x - 4 + np.random.randn(200)

plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.show()
```

or change the last part

```
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o')
plt.show()
```

take a look at some great resources: [Jakevdp blog](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.02-simple-scatter-plots.html)
and [Matplotlib's own documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html)